# Is Jolyne in the SBR universe, if so before or after part 8

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

In part 6 the universe is reset and everyone who was alive before the reset is put in the new universe. Is Jolyne in the SBR universe and if so is she set after or before part 8?

Comment: @pilgrim Sometimes there being no answer could be the correct answer. Perhaps you can elaborate a bit more as to why you believe this to only be speculation?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from the ending of part 6, is that the universe that we see in the end is not the SBR universe. It's another different Universe.

Reason why I think so:

The Jotaro we see in the end of part 6 doesn't exist in the SBR universe because we see the SBR version of Jotaro in part 8 as

> Kyo Nijimura

Answer (score 0):

Obviously major spoilers for Part 6. You are warned.

---

First of all, let's get the facts straight:

- The universe is reset **2** times. (let's call the original universe U0, after first the reset it becomes U1, then after the second reset it is U2)
- The first reset is by Pucci. Every soul who was alive in U0 is transferred to U1. Those who are dead are replaced by a similar but different new soul.
- Jolyne Cujoh dies in U0 so the "Jolyne" of U1 is a different soul. She is not the Jolyne of Part 6. The only survivor from the group of Part 6 is Emporio who is transferred to U1.
- Emporio kills Pucci in U1 while the universe is accelerating. This causes another reset without the influence of Pucci. The Pucci of Part 6 is not in U2.
- Jolyne's counterpart in U2 is Irene. She is not a prisoner.

---

So, "*is Jolyne in the SBR universe, if so before or after part 8*"?

If you are asking about Jolyne of U0, she is dead.

If you are asking about Jolyne of U1 (who has seemingly turned into Irene), there is no information regarding her in Part 7 or 8.

Answer (score 0):

No. Jolyne died with the other Stone Ocean protagonists (besides Emporio) at the end of the part. They received alternate universe counterparts which Emporio met after Pucci reset the universe - and the universe that they exist in has been dubbed the 'Ireneverse' by fans. The universe in which Steel Ball Run and JoJolion take place in (the 'SBRverse') is separate to both of these continuities, so there is no way that she could return.